# Сравнение массивов в процентном соотношении

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, как с помощью функции сравнить строки из двух массивов и вернуть процентное совпадение между сравниваемыми строками ?
Например:
Massiv_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
Massiv_2 = ['r', 'u', 'p']
функция должна выводить результат: строка из Massiv_2, строка из Massiv_1, % схожести между ними

Comment: С помощью этой штуки можно сравнить две строки: https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio Вам ее использовать для перебора двух списков и перекрестного сравнения. А вообще, вопрос не о чем, нехватает алгоритма сравнения и примеров: входные данные, результат

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ещё эту библиотеку часто используют https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy  Но нужна конкретика всё-таки, это всё не так просто, как кажется.

Comment: Пока писал ответ, в комментариях уже все написали...

Answer (score 0):

Я могу предложить такой вариант:

```
import difflib

def similarity(s1, s2):
  matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, s1, s2)
  return matcher.ratio()
  
 
string_1 = list('Пример первой строки.')
string_2 = list('Пример второй строки?')

print(f'Процент схожести двух списков составляет: {int(similarity(string_1, string_2) * 100)}%')
```

Вывод:

```
Процент схожести двух списков составляет: 80%
```

С помощью библиотеки [difflib](https://devdocs.io/python%7E3.7/library/difflib) можно так же сравнивать строки.

Comment: Мне нужно немного по другому: Massiv_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] и Massiv_2 = ['r', 'u', 'p']. Функция должна выводить результат: строка из Massiv_2, строка из Massiv_1, % схожести между ними.